# should i use php return to rexecuta a script

Tags: php

So... I'm a newbie in php and I want to read every line from a file, execute my script and then cameback to read a new line and execute again the script. My script is about reading links from a target specified so I decided to make it to read a target from a file to learning something new.

Here's my code for reading every lines from a file

```
<?
$handle = fopen("targets.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
    }
} else {
    echo "Can't open the file.";
} 
fclose($handle);
?>
```

and here is the script code:

```
$site = "http://www.example.com";

...script code...
```

so basicly I want for my $site variable to be every line from target.txt I tried to implement both like $site = "$line"; but it give me errors and I read something about return command... how should I build for my example?

Comment: `$site = file_get_contents('targets.txt')`? You can always implode an array of `$lines[] = $line; implode("\n", $lines)` to get the same results with fopen as well.

Comment: So you want to read all lines/urls in your text file, and then get the contents for each url/line?

Comment: no, read every line from the file and then with every line execute my script and my script need a url to start and work, so every time when read a line to execute the script with that value and then return read another line and execute again with the new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT sounds like you should be using a function:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("targets.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $line = do_something( $line );
    echo $line;
  }
} else {
  echo "Can't open the file.";
} 
fclose($handle);

function do_something( $line ) {

  // do something with $line...

  return $line;
}
```

Notice that with this type of function declaration you must return the value you created within your function and re-assign it back to the "source" variable.

Comment: This works but only with a target in the file, if there was 2 or more target it give me an error...